# -Like vs -Match with escaped RegEx special characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to look for two strings in a string, and the strings include Regex special characters.
I can successfully use a RegEx like this

```
if ( ($logFileNameConstruct -Match [regex]::escape('[Px~Error]')) -and ($logFileNameConstruct -Match [regex]::escape('[Px~Status]')) ) {
```

But I like to avoid RegEx when not specifically needed, and my understanding has always been that -Like is always looking for the literal string, so I expected success with this

```
if ( ($logFileNameConstruct -Like '*[Px~Error]*') -and ($logFileNameConstruct -Like '*[Px~Status]*') ) {
```

But it erroniously always returns true. On a lark I tried -Like with double quotes as well. Neither way works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are reserved in wildcard matches to specify a range (e.g. `[0-5]`) or list (e.g. `[012345]`) of characters to match.

See:

```
Get-Help about_Wildcards
```

There's no provision for escaping them, so in this case I think you're going to have to rely `-match` and regex.

Comment: Ah, somehow I thought -Like had no wildcards or special characters. Thanks for setting me straight.